# How to change the back button label, react-navigation

Tags: react-native, locale, react-navigation

I'm using react-navigation, and I can't change the locale of the default 'back' button.

In my Stack Navigator, if I write down a title for the main page, and if it's not too long, it will display the page title instead of 'back'.

```
export const Root = StackNavigator({
Index: {
    screen: Index,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        title: "My App name", //Not working when too long
    }),
},
```

How can I do that ?

[image: Default back button]

Comment: <Stack.Screen  options={{ headerBackTitle:"Back"}}/>

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use [`headerBackTitle`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack#headerBackTitle) prop to control back button title.

> **headerBackTitle**
>
> Title string used by the back button on iOS, or null to disable label. Defaults to the previous scene's `headerTitle`

**Example**

```
const SomeNavigator = StackNavigator({
   Main: { screen: Main },
   Login: { 
     screen: Login,
     navigationOptions: {
       headerBackTitle: 'some label'
     }
   }
 });
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it programmatically in login screen code ? I would like to personalize it and translate it...

Comment: You may need to arrange it (`headerBackTitle: null`) in the options part (the second parameter) of the createStackNavigator or StackNavigator in App.

Comment: How do I set the default `headerBackTitle`? If I specify it in my stack navigator then all screens will have that title, but I only want the custom header back title when the previous screen's title is too long

Answer (score 37):

**UPDATE as of version 5**

As of version 5, it is the option `headerBackTitleVisible` in `screenOptions`

Example of usage:

```
<Stack.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    headerBackTitleVisible: false
  }}
>
  <Stack.Screen name="route-name" component={ScreenComponent} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

if you want only to hide in the single screen you can do this by setting the `screenOptions` on the screen component see below for example:

```
<Stack.Screen options={{headerBackTitleVisible: false}} name="route-name" component={ScreenComponent} />
```

Answer (score 8):

Actually, when I update `react-navigation` to version three, the back button appears a title.

[image]

So I pass a `null` to `headerBackTitle` and set a component to `headerBackImage` and I got bellow UI that I desired:

[image]

So write like below:

```js
defaultNavigationOptions: {
  headerBackImage: <GoBack />,
  headerBackTitle: null,
};
```

**hint:** please use `defaultNavigationOptions` instead of `navigationOptions`.

### Update (v5.x)

In the newer version, there is `headerBackTitleVisible` option key that gets boolean values by setting it to `false` the back title will disappear.

```js
defaultNavigationOptions: {
  headerBackImage: <GoBack />,
  headerBackTitleVisible: false,
};
```

Comment: setting `headerBackTitleVisible: false` worked for me

Comment: Dear @a_rahmanshah, This answer is for a long time ago, at that moment there was no `headerBackTitleVisible` option key.

Answer (score 7):

`headerBackTitle = null` and `headerBackTitle = ''` both didnt worked in my case but in second option add single space like `headerBackTitle = ' '` gives me my desired look. It removes the text and added single space.

Comment: Also for `4.3.x` the option `headerBackTitleVisible: false` works too.

Answer (score 1):

```
<MyStack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerTruncatedBackTitle: 'translated back label',
      }}   
    >
```

**Version 5.x:** This solution preserves the actual behavior of React Navigation. The back button is shown only if the route name is too long.

Answer (score 0):

```
    UserProfile: {
    screen: UserProfile,
    navigationOptions: () => ({
      title:'Profile',
      headerBackImage: <Icon name="remove" 
                            size={25} 
                            color="white" />,
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
      headerRight:<Icon style={{paddingRight:30}}
                        name="edit" 
                        size={25} 
                        color="white"></Icon>,

     //headerTintColor: 'Colors.DarkBlue',
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#0049b8',
        TextColor:'white',
      },
    }),
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

use `headerTruncatedBackTitle` for change truncated back title.

Answer (score -3):

From v5 you can hide the title like this.

<Stack.Navigator
screenOptions={{ headerBackTitleVisible: false }}>

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).